# Search for a famous theorem

Tags: number-theory

The question asks to use a famous theorem to solve the problem below, but I don't know what the theorem is. Anyone can help with it:

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $p> 2$

Let $k$ be a strictly positive natural number $(k > 0)$

if $p | 2^k - 1$ ( $2^k -1 $ is divisible by $p$)

please show k as a function of p?

Comment: Immediate conclusion : ord$_{p}2$ divides $k$

Comment: How can $k$ be a function of $p$? $(p,k)=(3,2)$ and $(p,k)=(3,4)$ both satisfy the above relation.

Comment: can you tell me what is the name of this theorem? Thank you!

Comment: You may be thinking of "Fermat's Little Theorem", but the phrasing of the question is hard to understand.

Comment: thank you, you are right. It is the Fermat's Little Theorem. and k = p - 1